# invalide identifier oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE type recommendation as object(
    descriptions varchar2(200)
);


create type recomand as table of recommendation;



create type traitement_type as object (
id_traitement number(7),
    duree varchar2(25),
    recome recomand,
    description varchar2(250)
    
);


CREATE TABLE Traitement (primary key(id_traitement))
nested table recome store as Les_recommendations;
```

i execute these commands and at the last query i got the error :

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Your create table statement doesn't include a column list. It's interpreting "primary key" a column and spaces are not allowed. Look up the proper format for create table statements and PK constraints.